# c# dictionary calling value with key problem

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, key-value

```
Dictionary fruit<string,string> = new Dictionary<string,string>();
fruit.Add("name","orange");
fruit.Add("vitamin","C");
```

I want call value with key.
But, if i am write 
fruit.Key, 
c# is giving "name" 
what is problem?

Comment: do you want to get the value? if so, it is easy just fruit["KEY"] should give you the value!

Comment: Please add more detail about what your problem is. This code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Both will work:

```
string name = fruit["name"];
```

or:

```
string vit = fruit.Single(c => c.Key == "vitamin").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here (from my worktable) :

```
WhatisMethodForGetValue()  {
//????????????????????????????
}



  var tas = new Dictionary<string, string>();

      string sayi;
            string renk;
            bool okey = false;

                    tas["sayi"] = seriler[j];
                    tas["renk"] = renkler[i];
                    tas["okey"] = okey.ToString();



  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> mytas in (dynamic)TAS[v])
                {


Button Tas = new Button();
                    Tas.BackColor = Color.White;
Tas.Text = WhatisMethodForGetValue(mytas["sayi"]);
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer. Perhaps you meant to **edit** your question?